# Unity C# camera movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm currently trying to create a Camera Control for unity (to follow around a prefab and be able to zoom and such ...

> ***I am very new to C#***

an issue I am having with this script is that

- camera zooming to 0,0,0. (when I need it to stay at it's current Y-axis, I tried changing the void "Move()" but the vector requires 3 m_....'s

> I also need to  write a piece of code that will allow the player to zoom the camera in and out using the 
>   scroll wheel... (In "Public Void Update()"...

I've been looking through guides and videos and can't find anything to assist me with this..

### this is the section of code I require help with :

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();
}

private void Move()
{
    m_DesiredPosition = m_target.position;
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position,
        m_DesiredPosition, ref m_MoveVelocity, m_DampTime);
}

public void Update()
{
    // Get the scroll value of the mouse scroll wheel
    // float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

    // Is the scroll value not 0?

    // Modify the orthographic size by the scroll value
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = 4.8f;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For keeping the camera at Y = 0 simply override Y:

```
m_DesiredPosition = m_Target.position;
m_DesiredPosition.Y = 0;
transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position,
    m_DesiredPosition, ref m_MoveVelocity, m_DampTime);
```

For zooming the camera you'll want to add/subtract the value to orthographicsize instead of simply setting it:

```
// Zoom in
Camera.main.orthographicSize -= 4.8f;
// Zoom out
Camera.main.orthographicSize += 4.8f;
```

Comment: cheers, how would I implement the zoom in and out code to happen when i scroll the mouse wheel ... and do happen to know why this issue is happening ... http://i.imgur.com/Kwb2GhQ.png

Comment: The formatting will look bad here, but you're going to want to check the input of the mouse scroll wheel:

     if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0)
    {
        // zoom out
        Camera.main.orthographicSize += 4.8f;
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")  > 0)
    {
        // zoom in
        Camera.main.orthographicSize -= 4.8f;
    }